# DolphinDB: Function "moving" gives an error

Tags: aggregate-functions, moving-average, dolphindb

In DolphinDB, the script `moving(def(x,y)->avg(abs(x-y.last())), [tp,sma], timeP)` gives an error message: function must be an aggregate function.
However it is working in 2.00.1 but not in 2.00.2
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions must be defined with `defg` in the new version.

You can use the following two methods to call user-defined aggregate functions with function `moving`.

- By calling named aggregate functions

```sql
defg avg_abs(x,y){return avg(abs(x-y.last()))}
moving(avg_abs, [tp,sma], timeP)
```

- By calling anonymous aggregate functions (In version 2.00.3 or later)

```sql
moving(defg(x,y)->avg(abs(x-y.last())), [tp,sma], timeP)
```